# Is MS-PL (Microsoft Public License) code allowed in commercial product?

Tags: open-source, licensing

If someone wants to use parts of a code licensed under MS-PL and use it in a commercial product, is that allowed by MS-PL?  What are the restrictions.

Comment: This question is a "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" No? If it's off topic then where should this question be asked? Please reopen.

Comment: See [Questions about licensing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing)

Comment: [Understanding the Microsoft Public License (MS-PL)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/85301/98103)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's the Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL). Yes, you can pretty much do whatever you want with the code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff648068(v=pandp.10)

However, do read the conditions. Ones worth noting:

- If you distribute any portion of the software, you must retain all copyright, patent, trademark, and attribution notices that are present in the software.
- If you distribute any portion of the software **in source code form**, you may do so only under this license by including a complete copy of this license with your distribution. If you distribute any portion of the software in compiled or object code form, you may only do so under a license that complies with this license.

NOTE: the MS-PL appears to be deliberately incompatible with the GPL.

Comment: Is this substantially different than the BSD or Apache license?

Comment: Yes, I think is a "BSD style" license.

Comment: Except that it appears to be deliberately incompatible with the GPL, which I deplore.  There's enough license incompatibilities already, and making more is a Bad Thing.

Comment: As I see the 2 conditions you mentioned only apply to the actual ASP.NET MVC code/binaries. So you can't relicense their code. But you can license your code as you wish as long as you add a copy of Ms-PL license with your project.

Comment: The incompatibility with the GPL ought to be pointed out *in* the answer rather than in the comments.

Comment: ok, I added the following "NOTE: the MS-PL appears to be deliberately incompatible with the GPL." and updated the broken link.