# Wiki code parser for .NET and BSD-like licensed

Tags: .net, parsing, wiki, wiki-markup

I need a wiki code parser on top of Microsoft .NET and licensed under BSD, Apache or similar open source licenses.

Looking at other site's questions and *googling* I found the so-called ScrewTurn Wiki, which is a great product and it has its source publicly available, but it's licensed under GPLv2, and I don't want to be restricted to turn my project into "free software", and stay *open source*.

Currently I'm using Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0, so if there's no wiki parser in C# or VB.NET, and there's one in Python and it can be used with DLR and IronPython, it can be a valid solution, but if I can stay away of dynamic languages, it'd be better for me.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WikiPlex](http://wikiplex.codeplex.com) is the wiki engine behind [CodePlex](http://codeplex.com).

It's under the [Microsoft Public License](http://wikiplex.codeplex.com/license), which I believe [allows you to use it without open sourcing your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633132/is-ms-pl-microsoft-public-license-code-allowed-in-commercial-product).

Comment: Well, it's not about not open-sourcing my project, but stay in a license that allows everyone to use my code and integrated one in _open_ and _closed_ source projects.