# Commercial alternatives to DotNetZipLib for encrypted file containers

Tags: c#, .net, file, encryption, containers

I am reluctant to use open source alternatives for encrypted file containers.

Any suggestions for commercial ones?

System.IO.Packaging.EncryptedPackageEnvelop seems like too much effort to implement and the examples out there don't seem to support too much of the ZIP functionality.

Comment: Isn't your motivation inverted? I'd approach this from exactly the opposite angle... encryption should preferrably be open source and subject to review. The temptation of proprietary vendors is to downplay breaches and vulns because it's not in their commercial interest to do so. Look at RSA's lack of transparency over their breach. What is "highly" encrypted vs vanilla encrypted?

Comment: Compelling argument for open source but my requirement is for a solution that combines a file container with encryption. I do plan on further encrypting that with a public-key implementation. Furthermore, I am looking for a commercial solution since my own product will be licensed as closed-source and commercial.

Comment: Vanilla encryption... Lol... I removed the 'highly' bit from the question.

Comment: I'd just go with a ZIP (sure, change the extension and the magic number if you feel like it) containing files each individually encrypted with, say, AES.

Comment: Licenses such as MIT,BSD,MS-PL, Apache can easily be used in commercial closed source products, you don't even have to release any changes to the open source code.

Comment: @jbtule: In that case, you should post your comment as an answer. Also, where could I find more about these licenses? Reading the license file itself would be complete greek to me.

Comment: @AKX: ZIP would be fine as long as I have a managed wrapper. I'd like to see what jbtule suggests in his answer.

Comment: In response to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447367), someone [suggested SecureBlackBox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8447744)

Comment: @Brian: Thanks. Judging from the features and licensing costs, this may well be the solution. You should post your comment as an answer and I will revert back after evaluating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

> creates AES-encrypted zip archives for privacy of archived content

Has [examples](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples) too.

[MS-PL](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/ms-pl) licensed & while open source can be used with closed source products without releasing the source.

Comment: I know the title is commercial alternatives to DotNetZipLib, but since in the comments asker's main issue is that the consuming product will be closed source commercial and that is not an issue with DotNetZip's License. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633132/is-ms-pl-microsoft-public-license-code-allowed-in-commercial-product

Comment: That's exactly right. I was seriously considering SecureBlackBox but your fact will probably change that in favor of DotNetZip. I'll mark whatever we end up choosing as the right answer. Thanks.