# WPF - Create wizard with metro UI for C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

Im using visual studio 2012 premium and I need to create wizard  which will start from the visual studio. my question is there is a way to create it like a metro style look and feel,(im new to this topic :))if yes how?
I try to find data on the web without success...

I need to create simple wizard with 3 steps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/guides/quick-start.html) to achieve metro look and feel almost instantly. Have tried it, awesomely simple.

**UPDATE :**

MahApps.Metro licensed under [Microsoft Public License - MS-PL](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/LICENSE) which allow commercial use according to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633132/is-ms-pl-microsoft-public-license-code-allowed-in-commercial-product).

You also have some other options available such as [Modern UI For WPF](http://mui.codeplex.com/) and [Elysium](http://elysium.codeplex.com/). But [I still recommend MahApps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556540/metro-ui-for-wpf-differences/20560420#20560420) because it doesn't change much of the way you code. You can use standard WPF control and MahApps will style those controls to appear in Metro look-and-feel.

Comment: I can use it for my project for free?

Comment: Yes, even commercial use is encouraged (i read that somewhere, but forgot where. will add comment if i found the link to that statement).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should Try [Devexpress](https://www.devexpress.com/) library ...
it contains varieties of UI's ...

Comment: -1. DevExpress WPF controls are nearly useless. They don't fit into MVVM and you'll have a hard time trying to fit them into your WPF project unless you really love a 2000 line code behind file.