# Metro UI for WPF differences

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-metro, mahapps.metro, modern-ui

Does exist any real difference among "Modern UI for WPF", "MahApps" and "Elysium"?

What would you suggest?

I can find any list of features, or comparison. Testing them all deeply would take some time, so if anyone has already through this, I'd really appreciate him to share experience.

Answer (score 2):

I did similar mini research about this. I compared MahApps.Metro and Modern UI back then, and finally choosed MahApps for use in my project. The main reason is simplicity. Adopting MahApps to my project demanding less effort. As far as i know MahApps is mostly style, not custom control (except MetroWindow to replace standard WPF Window, and some additional control). Therefore, the whole code stay WPF standard code and markup, only the appearance of those standard controls overriden by MahApps style.

And speaking about customizable, MahApps library is open source so you can modify predefined MahApps styles to meet your needs. And you can architect your apps, and apply all pattern applicable to WPF, because as i told your code mostly stay WPF standard.

Not a comperhensive comparison, just wanna share what i went through. I mostly speaking about MahApps because that is what i've been using. Maybe someone else will come up with the other two.

Comment: MahApps doesn't support Windows XP though :-( I tried it's first sloppy before then it even errors out.

Comment: See how to combine [Material Design, Dragablz, MahApps](https://dragablz.net/2015/02/25/material-design-in-xaml-mash-up/) - combining 3 of [top 10 WPF Nugets](https://nugetmusthaves.com/article/top-wpf-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

All of them modifies the base Templates of WPF Controls. Regardless of their "beauty", I'd choose one that is easy to Customize, maintain and documentation.

I personally never used one, but *Modern UI* is quite famous, sort of maintainable, have a lot of resources if you search and their site provides some tutorials on how to customize. If you haven't a lot of experience in WPF Templates, Styling, all of them will be hard to digest.

If that's not your case, choose the customizable one - whichever it is.

By customizable I mean not only the appearance, but the whole WPF purpose, architecture and patterns.